# Is there an explanation given for humans lost capacity for speech in so short a time evolutionarily speaking?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes

(Note, I realize that later versions had the anti-alzheimer's virus which increased ape intelligence ironically damaged human minds. How neatly explained that was -- I am interested in the original series and novelizations.)

In Planet of the Apes, humans have no only lost the power of speech but clearly much of their intelligence. I think the idea is that they are about like modern-day chimps although the do wear clothing but that may not mean much besides a movie wherein all humans were naked could not have been released then or even now.

2000 years (that's how much time has passed, right?) is not nearly enough. I am wondering if a novelization or a sequel offers an explanation -- one thought is that the same radiation that caused mutants with vast mental powers (not sure if more intelligent but definitely had telepathy and could cause illusions -- kind of like the aliens in the Star Trek pilot) also affected the remainder of humanity.

And yet I recall thinking that what the film tried to convey was simply that as the apes gained ascendancy, the humans, forced to live in primitive ways, became primitive mentally.

Comment: It only takes a generation to wipe out culture.  Zira's research and Nova eventually saying a word demonstrates the physiology for speech is still there.  I'd speculate (not answer) during the brief period when humans were apparently domesticated speaking was trained out.  And the wild population perhaps had a survival benefit from being reduced to hand gestures.  Note if you create a grand unified universe and include the TV series it is only the New York humans that don't talk.  I'd assume mostly Rod Serling and Pierre Boulle (novel) was just doing a role reversal for the apes and humans.

Comment: I thought it was a shame the new movies did not get to the far future and show the anti-alzheimer's virus had created telepathic mutants like in Beneath the Planet of the Apes.

Comment: @lucasbachmann: I think a more sophisticated treatment of the mutants would have been better. But was not the idea that the mutants had been created by the bomb and that's why they worshipped it?

Comment: @lucasbachmann: I guess a bunch of kids born into a Mad Max-like world might grow up without literacy and with limited vocabularies but hard to believe humans would even after 100 generations stop speaking. More likely they would redevelop written human language. My money is on repression by the apes. Indeed, perhaps the apes cull the smartest humans in a deliberate attempt to breed unintelligent humans. They do have expeditions to capture humans, we saw this.

Comment: @lucasbachmann: where was it shown that only NY humans don't talk? How ironic that is -- I lived in Manhattan and they sure talk.

Comment: The 1974 TV series takes place in California. The year is different too but given how inconsistent the movies are its not worth digging into.  See episode 2 https://youtu.be/Zzg38T6s6Jw - also my mutant comment would be if the new movies had them it would be logical fan fiction to tie it to the brain virus.  They are entirely different continuities- though the first movie did have a line on the news about a missing Mars Mission as I recall- setting up a potential sequel to be more like the original story.